# error: wide character array initialized from incompatible wide string

Tags: c, unicode, compiler-errors, c-strings

I've searched around, but I haven't found any valuable information regarding this error.

```
typedef struct {

        unsigned short string[];

} s;

const s str = {

        .string = L"George Morgan"

};
```

SOLUTION:

```
typedef struct {

        int string[];

} s;

const s str = {

        .string = L"George Morgan"

};
```

It was as simple as an `int`.

Comment: What compiler, what OS, what exact error message? Does your compiler have `wchar_t`? Which C-standard does the compiler support, which one did you tell it to use?

Comment: GCC, I'm writing an OS, the one in the title. No. Everything up to C99. C99.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was using `int` instead of using `unsigned short` for the initialization of the unicode string.

Answer (score 3):

A string literal prefixed with `L` is stored in an array of `wchar_t` and you'll fix the error you observed by using it. You need to include the header `wchar.h` to access it. Also, `sizeof(s)` is a constant, so it clearly cannot depend on what string it is initialized with. From this it is easy to see, that you must provide the array's range.

```
#include <wchar.h>

#define S_STRING_LEN 256

typedef struct {
     wchar_t string[S_STRING_LEN];
} s;

const s str = { .string = L"George Morgan" };
```

Comment: I thought that wchar_t was defined as `unsigned short`. I'm trying to write library independent code, so I need just the definition. Also, the string length shouldn't matter in the definition of string, as it resides in a typedef. Actually populating the string in the struct defines the string length.

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan no, the standard does not require that. It depends on the implementation.

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan Your other claim also seems to be unfounded: `a.c:4:17: error: flexible array member in otherwise empty struct` on line `wchar_t string[]`, gcc 4.7.2

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan are you trying to avoid including `wchar.h`? It's part of the C standard library, so you may very well assume users of your code will have it.

Comment: Ah, well having a single flexible array in an otherwise empty structure would throw that error. I have other variables inside my structure above the string, I just took them out for simplicity sake. And yes, I am avoiding it because I am writing an operating system. It has to remain library independent.

Comment: No problem at all. So, can you assist me in avoiding wchar_t, and solving this problem?

Comment: @GeorgeMorgan try using `int`? Although I don't know of a portable way to avoid wchar_t, and I don't advocate it, either.

Comment: Wow. I have no idea how I missed that! Thank you very much. Also, portability is something that I am able to work out using a config file, as I am actually typedef-ing int to wchar_t for my specific application.

Comment: `wchar_t` should be defined in `<stddef.h>`, which is part of the compiler, not the operating system or any library.  Why do you want to avoid wchar_t as its more portable?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem as follows at Arduino and found the solution.

```
  struct Mesaj { 
    byte MakineNo[2] = "1";  //The ERROR POINT
    byte Nem[3];
    byte Sicaklik[4];
    int id;
  } mesaj;
```

The Solution is:

```
 struct Mesaj { 
    byte MakineNo[2]; // Remove the numbers and
    byte Nem[3];
    byte Sicaklik[4];
    int id;
  } mesaj;

  *(int*)(mesaj.MakineNo) = 1; //Added here!
```